# How to align the wizard to the left and right sides?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Briefly, this is my [current code](http://jsfiddle.net/z8bkjmfb/), and I want it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z8bkjmfb/3/).

How can I do that by fixing css?

```css
.nav-wizard {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-wizard > li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav-wizard > li > a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.nav-wizard > li > a .badge {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.nav-wizard > li:first-child > a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-wizard > li:not(:first-child) > a:before {
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px inset transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-wizard > li:not(:last-child) > a {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.nav-wizard > li:not(:last-child) > a:after {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px inset transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #eeeeee;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.nav-wizard > li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-wizard > li:last-child > a {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-wizard > li.done:hover > a,
.nav-wizard > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.nav-wizard > li.done:hover > a:before,
.nav-wizard > li:hover > a:before {
  border-right-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.nav-wizard > li.done:hover > a:after,
.nav-wizard > li:hover > a:after {
  border-left-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.nav-wizard > li.done > a {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
.nav-wizard > li.done > a:before {
  border-right-color: #e2e2e2;
}
.nav-wizard > li.done > a:after {
  border-left-color: #e2e2e2;
}
.nav-wizard > li.active > a,
.nav-wizard > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-wizard > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.nav-wizard > li.active > a:after {
  border-left-color: #428bca;
}
.nav-wizard > li.active > a .badge {
  color: #428bca;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-wizard > li.disabled > a {
  color: #777777;
}
.nav-wizard > li.disabled > a:hover,
.nav-wizard > li.disabled > a:focus {
  color: #777777;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: default;
}
.nav-wizard > li.disabled > a:before {
  border-right-color: #eeeeee;
}
.nav-wizard > li.disabled > a:after {
  border-left-color: #eeeeee;
}
.nav-wizard.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-wizard.nav-justified > li > a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-wizard.nav-justified > li > a {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .nav-wizard.nav-justified > li > a:before,
  .nav-wizard.nav-justified > li > a:after {
    border: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Nav Wizard Demo</h1>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav nav-wizard">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages to looooooooooooonnnngggggggggg</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <BR>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the right side of the wizard is not aligned to the right side of the `input` (The wizard's length is not equal to the input's).

I need the last part (with the `messages`) of the wizard to align to the right side of the `input`. How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No one can understand what are you trying to ask. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the "Messages" box stretch to the right edge of the input field?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to stretch to the right edge you should make the `ul` items `display: table;` and `width:100%;`. While the `li` items should be `display:table-cell;`.

```
.nav-wizard  {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
}

.nav-wizard > li {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: left;
}
```

See an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wm2j1q72/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to float the last item to the right but this may not be the optimum solution.

```
.nav-wizard > li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xabtaf58/2/)**

Comment: As I said, it's not the optimum solution.